# What species of fruit was this orange-like thing with a dark-green peel that I ate in Israel?

Tags: food-and-drink, middle-east

When I was in Israel, I bought a few avocados at a local market. I couldn't read the signs since they were in Hebrew, but I thought I could tell these were avocados by looking at them.

When I got them to my hostel and cut one open, I discovered I had actually bought citrus fruits similar to oranges. This was quite funny and also tasty. But I've wondered ever since, what were they?

They can't have been regular oranges, because they were ripe and ready to eat on the inside while being dark green on the outside. They were also oblong like avocados instead of round like oranges.

Does anyone know the real name of such fruit?

Comment: Maybe some variety of [*etrog* (citron)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etrog)?

Comment: An oroblanco/sweetie, perhaps?  These are common in Israel and exported widely. 
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oroblanco

Comment: Etrog is unlikely as it's only sold on specialty holiday markets around September. Oroblanco/sweetie also doesn't match the description well - larger than an orange, light green and not dark, not oblong. They also taste much more like grapefruit than an orange.

Answer (score 2):

My best guess would be an orange, possibly a Washington navel orange. Some of these can be ripe but green.

See [a catalog of Israeli citrus](https://www.agri.gov.il/download/files/CatalogHadar_1.pdf) - mostly Hebrew, but nice pictures and English names.